# BASH - Safe check before running "rm -fr $FOLDER"

Tags: bash, rm

I have a script which really needs an rm -fr on a specific folder

I'd like to make this as safe as possible. I started this script below but I was wondering if there's anything else I missed.

```
folder=""

if [[ ! -d "$folder" ]]; then
  echo "Error: is not a folder"
elif [[ "$folder" == "/" ]]; then
  echo "Error: folder points to root"
elif [[ "$folder" == "../"* ]]; then
  echo "Error: folder start with ../"
elif [[ "$folder" == *"/.."* ]]; then
  echo "Error: folder contains /.."
elif [[ "$folder" == *"/*"* ]]; then
  echo "Error: folder ends with /*"
else
  rm -fr "$folder"
fi
```

Update: added the check for "/"

Comment: May be check for `/` too?

Comment: Thanks I updated the code!

Comment: are all the folders located under a given user..eg ~/home/jsmith ?

Comment: In the script I have, the folder should be in /tmp and not in a user's home folder. But if you have anything to add that would cover all cases, feel free to share.

Comment: You are trying to blacklist the things you *don't* want to delete; have you tried whitelisting the things you *do* want to delete?

Comment: I'm trying to make code that I can reuse elsewhere. Whitelisting is not an option.

Comment: Well, you could have a reusable "blacklist" mechanism, coupled with a case-by-case whitelist check.  Just checking that their path is located inside a specific directory is a good starting point for a very simple whitelisting approach.  Your reusable script/function could take an argument to make that check, only requiring the caller to provide a directory name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be as safe as possible, you could perhaps...

Make sure any globbing is done first :

```
shopt -s nullglob
declare -a folders=(folder_or_glob)
```

Iterate over each element of the array, one at a time, and operate on the canonical path.

```
for f in "${folders[@]-}"
do
  [[ $f ]] || continue
  candidate="$(realpath -e -s "$f")" || continue
  ok_to_delete "$candidate" || continue
  rm -rf "$candidate"
done
```

Use function `ok_to_delete` to test :

```
ok_to_delete()
{
  [[ -d $1 ]] || continue     # Is directory
  [[ $1 != / ]] || continue   # Not root
  [[ "${1%/*}" ]] || continue # At least two levels deep
  (... add any test you want ...)
}
```

There is a bit of redundancy here (e.g. not root + 2 levels deep), but this is just to give you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the path name of folder, I would rather to check the contents in that folder, file's size/user/timestamp/keywork/extension, etc, or whatever you care most about. This is a more safe method for you, this's just my two cents.